# Friend Dropped iPhone. Is it okay?

Tags: iphone

Okay, so I have a speck candy shell grip on my phone, I have never dropped my phone before but yesterday I let my friend do something on it in the YMCA and he dropped it. It was only from no more than about two feet and it fell on the spongy-soft floor. I'm really paranoid something may have happened but there is no damage and it functions no differently. 100% perfect. Any way anyone can put my mind at ease?

Comment: There is no 100% guarantee, but if you do not see anything from the outside and do not experience any functional differences (e.g. touch, buttons, etc. still working), I would say it survived it.  The majority of internal damage happens when there is also outside damage (like dents or cracks), which puts the pressure onto internal parts allowing for dust/dirt to settle or them to crack as well.  Again: Test all built-in functions (touchscreen, buttons, camera, ...) and see if they are still working.  If they are, all ok, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone is fine. The Speck CandyShell cases offer excellent protection. In general, the iPhone often takes falls quite well with the particular exception of shattered screens if it falls onto concrete/rock. I dropped my previous iPhone 4S multiple times and it was still in great condition. One time it fell from about 3' onto concrete and survived with just some scratching and minor dings to the metal.

As a side note, my personal opinion is that the Speck CandyShell (while they last) is not at all far off from the Otterbox Defender that many people have: so you phone was well protected. I suspect you wouldn't notice a difference even if there was no case, though with that fall.

So, don't worry about it and your phone is just fine.